# TQMLS1028A error with Open Industrial Linux " Unable to read file fsl-ls1028a-mbls1028a.dtb "

Tags: linux, makefile, u-boot, nxp-microcontroller

I am trying to build the Open Industrial Linux Image and I am facing some problems when I try to run the builded image in the TQMLS1028A

I try to build the image with an Linux Mint 19.3 with the kernel 5.0.21-rt16 and with an Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS with the kernel 4.15.0-112 generic. When I make the Image with both Linux gives the same error when the board boots

I format the SDCard to be a boot device with Rufus Version 3.11, because for some reason that I dont understand when I use the command

`sudo dd if=./sdcard.img of=/dev/mmcblk0`

The SDcard doesnt recognize the image and it doesnt work at all. So that is why I use Rufus to copy the image inside of the SDCard.

After putting the Image inside of the SDCard I try to start my MBLS1028A-IND and it is giving me the error "unable to read the file fsl-ls1028a-mbks1028a.dtb"

Here are the complete logs of the error that is giving the board.

[Error give in the board boots Page1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iq02.png)

[Error give when the board boots Page1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4fm6.png)

Additionally I have the output logs when I was building the image with the command "make all". If you need them let me know and I can send them.

If there any hint of what else I can do? If you need any other information let me know.

As request here is the text what is on the images

```
    U-Boot SPL 2018.03 (Dec 23 2020 - 02:20:50 +0100)
    Initialzing DDR using fixed setting
    Configuring DDR for 1600 MT/s data rate
    Trying to boot from MMC1
    
    
    U-Boot 2018.03 (Dec 23 2020 - 02:20:50 +0100)
    
    SoC:  LS1028AE Rev1.0 (0x870b0010)
    Clock Configuration:
           CPU0(A72):1300 MHz  CPU1(A72):1300 MHz  
           Bus:      400  MHz  DDR:      1600 MT/s
    Reset Configuration Word (RCW):
           00000000: 34004010 00000030 00000000 00000000
           00000010: 00000000 008e0000 0030c000 00000000
           00000020: 00a03150 00002580 00000000 00008096
           00000030: 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000
           00000040: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
           00000050: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
           00000060: 00000000 00000000 000e7000 00000000
           00000070: eb580000 03000000
    Model: TQMLS1028A on MBLS1028A
    Board: MBLS1028A Booting from: SD
    I2C:   ready
    DRAM:  958 MiB (DDR4, 32-bit, CL=11, ECC on)
    FSL_SDHC: 0, FSL_SDHC: 1
    PPA Firmware: Version ebbd1ea
    Using SERDES1 Protocol: 60248 (0xeb58)
    PCIe0: pcie@3400000 disabled
    PCIe1: pcie@3500000 Root Complex: no link
    MMC:   Loading Environment from MMC... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment
    
    Failed (-5)
    In:    serial
    Out:   serial
    Err:   serial
    TQMLS1028A EEPROM:
      ID: TQMLS1028A-P1.103
      SN: 72927904
      MAC: 00:d0:93:4a:77:f6
    Net:   phy path: /pcie@1f0000000/netc_mdio/phy@3
    phy path: /pcie@1f0000000/netc_mdio/phy@0
    eth0: enetc#0, eth1: enetc#1 [PRIME], eth2: enetc#2, eth3: netc_mdio
    Warning: enetc#3 (eth4) using random MAC address - fa:4f:8a:fa:a8:bd
    , eth4: enetc#3
    trying to set up RGMII
    trying to set up QSGMII for SERDES x5xx!!!!
    Hit any key to stop autoboot:  3  2  1  0 
    Booting from sd card ...
    102464 bytes read in 22 ms (4.4 MiB/s)
    Loading hdp firmware from 0x0000000082000000 offset 0x0000000000002000
    Loading hdp firmware Complete
    9721536 bytes read in 679 ms (13.7 MiB/s)
    Uncompressed size: 22053376 = 0x1508200
    ** Unable to read file fsl-ls1028a-mbls1028a.dtb **
    libfdt fdt_check_header(): FDT_ERR_BADMAGIC
    No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
    the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
    Aborting!
    No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
    the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
    Aborting!
    Setting bus to 5
    Setting bus to 5
    ERROR: Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree
    Could not find a valid device tree
    Booting from emmc ...
    ** No partition table - mmc 1 **
    Loading hdp firmware from 0x0000000082000000 offset 0x0000000000002000
    Loading hdp firmware Complete
    ** No partition table - mmc 1 **
    Uncompressed size: 22053376 = 0x1508200
    ** No partition table - mmc 1 **
    libfdt fdt_check_header(): FDT_ERR_BADMAGIC
    No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
    the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
    Aborting!
    No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
    the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
    Aborting!
    Setting bus to 5
    Setting bus to 5
    ERROR: Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree
    Could not find a valid device tree
    Booting from SPI NOR flash...
    SF: Detected mx66u51235f with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 64 MiB
    device 0 offset 0x480000, size 0x80000
    SF: 524288 bytes @ 0x480000 Read: OK
    Loading hdp firmware from 0x0000000082000000 offset 0x0000000000002000
    Loading hdp firmware Complete
    SF: Detected mx66u51235f with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 64 MiB
    device 0 offset 0x500000, size 0xa00000
    SF: 10485760 bytes @ 0x500000 Read: OK
    Error: Bad gzipped data
    libfdt fdt_check_header(): FDT_ERR_BADMAGIC
    No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
    the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
    Aborting!
    No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
    the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
    Aborting!
    Setting bus to 5
    Setting bus to 5
    Bad Linux ARM64 Image magic!
    No boot device !!! reset
    =>
```

Here is the output of the `printenv` command of u-boot

```
    => printev nv
    addemmc=setenv bootargs ${bootargs} root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 rootfstype=ext4
    addsd=setenv bootargs ${bootargs} root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4
    addspi=setenv bootargs ${bootargs} root=ubi0_0 rw rootfstype=ubifs ubi.mtd=7
    addtty=setenv bootargs ${bootargs} console=ttyS0,115200
    addvideo=setenv bootargs ${bootargs} cma=256M video=1920x1080-32@60
    arch=arm
    baudrate=115200
    board=tqmls1028a_mbls1028a
    board_name=tqmls1028a
    boardinit=run resetusb; run resetphy;
    boot=SD
    bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/ram0 earlycon=uart8250,mmio,0x21c0500 ramdisk_size=0x2000000 default_hugepagesz=2m hugepagesz=2m hugepages=256
    bootcmd=run sdboot; run emmcboot; run spiboot; run panicboot
    bootdelay=3
    cpu=armv8
    emmcargs=run addemmc addtty addvideo
    emmcboot=echo Booting from emmc ...; setenv bootargs; run emmcargs; run emmchdpload; run emmcimageload; run emmcfdtload;run setmacaddr;run boardinit;booti ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
    emmcfdtload=fatload mmc 1:1 ${fdtaddr} ${fdt_file};
    emmchdpload=fatload mmc 1:1 ${loadaddr} ls1028a-dp-fw.bin; hdp load ${loadaddr};
    emmcimageload=fatload mmc 1:1 ${fdtaddr} Image.gz; unzip $fdtaddr $loadaddr
    eth1addr=00:d0:93:4a:77:f7
    eth2addr=00:d0:93:4a:77:f8
    eth3addr=00:d0:93:4a:77:f9
    ethact=enetc#1
    ethaddr=00:d0:93:4a:77:f6
    ethprime=enetc#1
    fdt_file=fsl-ls1028a-mbls1028a.dtb
    fdtaddr=0x88000000
    fdtcontroladdr=bba199d0
    firmwarepart=1
    gpio_expander_1_addr=0x25
    gpio_expander_2_addr=0x70
    gpio_expander_i2c_bus=5
    hwconfig=fsl_ddr:bank_intlv=auto
    kernel_file=Image.gz
    loadaddr=0x82000000
    mmcdev=1
    mmcsddev=0
    panicboot=echo No boot device !!! reset
    rcw_emmc_file=rcw_1300_emmc.bin
    rcw_max_size=1024
    rcw_qspi_file=rcw_1300_spi_nor.bin
    rcw_sd_file=rcw_1300_sd.bin
    rcw_sd_offset=0x8
    resetphy=i2c dev ${gpio_expander_i2c_bus}; i2c mw ${gpio_expander_2_addr} 0x3 0xd5; i2c mw ${gpio_expander_2_addr} 0x1 0xd5; sleep 0.1; i2c mw ${gpio_expander_2_addr} 0x1 0xff;
    resetusb=i2c dev ${gpio_expander_i2c_bus}; i2c mw ${gpio_expander_1_addr} 0x6.1 0xfd; i2c mw ${gpio_expander_1_addr} 0x2.1 0xfd; sleep 0.1; i2c mw ${gpio_expander_1_addr} 0x2.1 0xff;
    rootfs_mtddev=RootFS
    sdargs=run addsd addtty addvideo
    sdboot=echo Booting from sd card ...; setenv bootargs; run sdargs; run sdhdpload; run sdimageload; run sdfdtload;run setmacaddr;run boardinit;booti ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
    sdfdtload=fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdtaddr} ${fdt_file};
    sdhdpload=fatload mmc 0:1 ${loadaddr} ls1028a-dp-fw.bin; hdp load ${loadaddr};
    sdimageload=fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdtaddr} Image.gz; unzip $fdtaddr $loadaddr
    set_getcmd=if test "${ipmode}" != static; then setenv getcmd dhcp; setenv autoload yes; else setenv getcmd tftp; setenv autoload no; fi
    setmacaddr=fdt addr ${fdtaddr}; fdt resize 4;fdt set /soc/pcie@1f0000000/pci@0,5/port@0/ mac-address ${switch_mac_addr};
    soc=fsl-layerscape
    spiargs=run addspi addtty addvideo
    spiboot=echo Booting from SPI NOR flash...; setenv bootargs; run spiargs; run spihdpload spikernelload spifdtload ; run setmacaddr;run boardinit;booti ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr};
    spifdtload=sf probe 0; sf read ${fdtaddr} DTB
    spihdpload=sf probe; sf read ${loadaddr} HDP; hdp load ${loadaddr};
    spikernelload=sf probe 0; sf read ${fdtaddr} Linux; unzip ${fdtaddr} ${loadaddr}
    stderr=serial
    stdin=serial
    stdout=serial
    switch_mac_addr=[00 d0 93 4a 77 fb]
    uboot_emmc_file=u-boot-with-spl_emmc.bin
    uboot_max_size=0x300000
    uboot_qspi_file=u-boot-with-spl_qspi.bin
    uboot_sd_file=u-boot-with-spl_sdcard.bin
    uboot_sd_offset=0x800
    update_fdt_emmc=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${fdt_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then mmc dev ${mmcdev}; mmc rescan; echo Write fdt image to mmc ${mmcdev}:${firmwarepart}...; save mmc ${mmcdev}:${firmwarepart} ${loadaddr} ${fdt_file} ${filesize}; fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv getcmd 
    update_fdt_qspi=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${fdt_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then sf probe; sf update ${loadaddr} DTB ${filesize};fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv blkc; setenv getcmd 
    update_fdt_sd=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${fdt_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then mmc dev ${mmcsddev}; mmc rescan; echo Write fdt image to mmc ${mmcsddev}:${firmwarepart}...; save mmc ${mmcsddev}:${firmwarepart} ${loadaddr} ${fdt_file} ${filesize}; fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv getcmd 
    update_kernel_emmc=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${kernel_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then mmc dev ${mmcdev}; mmc rescan; echo Write kernel image to mmc ${mmcdev}:${firmwarepart}...; save mmc ${mmcdev}:${firmwarepart} ${loadaddr} ${kernel_file} ${filesize}; fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv getcmd 
    update_kernel_qspi=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${kernel_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then sf probe; sf update ${loadaddr} Linux ${filesize};fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv blkc; setenv getcmd 
    update_kernel_sd=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${kernel_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then mmc dev ${mmcsddev}; mmc rescan; echo Write kernel image to mmc ${mmcsddev}:${firmwarepart}...; save mmc ${mmcsddev}:${firmwarepart} ${loadaddr} ${kernel_file} ${filesize}; fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv getcmd 
    update_rcw_emmc=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${rcw_emmc_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then mmc dev ${mmcdev}; mmc rescan; setexpr blkc ${filesize} + 0x1ff; setexpr blkc ${blkc} / 0x200; if itest ${filesize} <= ${rcw_max_size}; then mmc write ${loadaddr} ${rcw_sd_offset} ${blkc}; fi; fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv blkc; setenv getcmd 
    update_rcw_qspi=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${rcw_qspi_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then if itest ${filesize} <= ${uboot_max_size}; then sf probe; sf update ${loadaddr} RCW ${filesize};fi; fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv blkc; setenv getcmd 
    update_rcw_sd=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${rcw_sd_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then mmc dev 0; mmc rescan; setexpr blkc ${filesize} + 0x1ff; setexpr blkc ${blkc} / 0x200; if itest ${filesize} <= ${rcw_max_size}; then mmc write ${loadaddr} ${rcw_sd_offset} ${blkc}; fi; fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv blkc; setenv getcmd 
    update_uboot_emmc=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${uboot_emmc_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then mmc dev ${mmcdev}; mmc rescan; setexpr blkc ${filesize} + 0x1ff; setexpr blkc ${blkc} / 0x200; if itest ${filesize} <= ${uboot_max_size}; then mmc write ${loadaddr} ${uboot_sd_offset} ${blkc}; fi; fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv blkc; setenv getcmd 
    update_uboot_qspi=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${uboot_qspi_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then if itest ${filesize} <= ${uboot_max_size}; then sf probe; sf update ${loadaddr} U-Boot-PBL ${filesize};fi; fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv blkc; setenv getcmd 
    update_uboot_sd=run set_getcmd; if ${getcmd} ${uboot_sd_file}; then if itest ${filesize} > 0; then mmc dev ${mmcsddev}; mmc rescan; setexpr blkc ${filesize} + 0x1ff; setexpr blkc ${blkc} / 0x200; if itest ${filesize} <= ${uboot_max_size}; then mmc write ${loadaddr} ${uboot_sd_offset} ${blkc}; fi; fi; fi; setenv filesize; setenv blkc; setenv getcmd 
    vendor=tqc
    
    Environment size: 7098/524284 bytes
    =>
```

Image of the partions of the SDCard

[Partions of the SD Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veclT.png)

[Partion of 268 Mb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJXAs.png)

[Partion of 3.1 Gb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9ErJ.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please: 1) replace the images by text that can be copied/pasted 2) augment your answer with  the output for the u-boot command `printenv`  (in text format, no more images please )?

Comment: Do you see the file when you mount the SD card? In which directory is it located?

Comment: I find the file ls1028a-mbls1028a.dtb in one of the partion that is made by rufus. Rufus make the SdCard to have two partions one of 3.1 GB and one of 268 MB, the file is located in the root of the partion of 268 MB. I attached two images where you can see the partiton and the files inside of each

Comment: @Frant I add the text that you requet

Comment: Thanks. According to `sdfdtload=fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdtaddr} ${fdt_file};`  `fsl-ls1028a-mbls1028a.dtb` is expected to reside in `mmc 0:1`. Can you see it using the u-boot commands  (should be something like `fatls mmc 0:1`) ? Can you copy it manually from your PC in the case it would not currently in mmac 0:1 ? An alternative would be to replace `sdfdtload=fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdtaddr} ${fdt_file};`  by an equivalent command that would load it from the  root of the partition of 268 MB you found it in.

Comment: Frant I am voting to delete the post so you can be the person who makes the answer

Comment: Its very kind of you, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `sdfdtload=fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdtaddr} ${fdt_file};` `fsl-ls1028a-mbls1028a.dtb` is expected to reside in `mmc 0:1`. It may just be missing or have a different name - I recently had a similar issue on a Marvell-based SBC.  An alternative would be to replace `sdfdtload=fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdtaddr} ${fdt_file};` by an equivalent command that would load it from the root of the partition of 268 MB you found it in, in the case it would not be `mmc 0:1` .

In the case you would have to modify your current u-boot environment, you should be able to make your changes persistent by using the `saveenv`u-boot command. A side effect should be to make the CRC-related warning message go away: it may be issued because there is currently no valid u-boot environment saved in flash at the location it should be stored at.

Comment: I think is good to remark that the issue was solved by changing the name of the file ls1028a-mbls1028a.dtb to fsl-ls1028a-mbls1028a.dtb, or another solution could have been to edit the parameter "fdt_file"